# UWP XAML Databinding working on one text box, but not another

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp

I'm running into a peculiar issue, where data-binding two text boxes to the same object works just fine, but after I load data back into my program via XML deserialization the binding fails on one of those text boxes.

I use a splitview to build a little hamburger navigation menu and load my pages into a frame

Here is the related XAML in my MainPage.xaml

```
<TextBlock Name="PlayerGoldTextBlock" 
                       RelativePanel.RightOf="PlayerNameTextBlock" 
                       RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" 
                       Foreground="Gold" 
                       FontSize="28" 
                       Text="{x:Bind myGame.Game.Player.Gold, Mode=OneWay}" />    
<TextBlock Name="RemainingTurnsTextBlock" 
                       RelativePanel.RightOf="PlayerGoldTextBlock" 
                       RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" 
                       Foreground="Red"  
                       Text="{x:Bind myGame.Game.RemainingTurns, Mode=OneWay}" />
<SplitView.Content>
       <Frame Name="MyFrame"></Frame>
</SplitView.Content>
```

In the page I have loaded into the frame:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10">
    <TextBlock Text="Gold:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="16" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind myGame.Game.Player.Gold, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="16" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

in MainPage: The PlayerGoldTextBlock fails to bind correctly after I load, but the RemainingTurnsTextBlock works fine

in my frame: x:Bind myGame.Game.Player.Gold seems to rebind just fine after I load.

Another thing, which may be related, is that upon loading I see the RemainingTurnsTextBlock update immediately, but the (working) player gold in the frame doesn't until I navigate to a different frame and then back

here is my deserialization code, in case that matters:

```
async public void LoadGame()
{
    var filename = "testsave.xml";
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GameModel));
    StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(filename).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
    Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    GameModel myGame;
    using (stream)
    {
        myGame = (GameModel)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => 
        {
            this.Player = myGame.Player;
            this.Locations = myGame.Locations;
            this.RemainingTurns = myGame.RemainingTurns;
        });
    }
}
```

here are some of the properties from my GameModel

```
public Player Player { get; set; }
public int MaxTurns { get; set; }
private int remainingTurns;
public int RemainingTurns
{
    get { return remainingTurns; }
    set { SetProperty(remainingTurns, value, () => remainingTurns = value);}
}
```

here is the gold property in player

```
private int gold;
public int Gold
{
    get { return gold; }
    set {SetProperty(gold, value, () => gold = value);}
}
```

here is setproperty

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>(T currentValue, T newValue, Action DoSet,
    [CallerMemberName] String property = null)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(currentValue, newValue)) return false;
    DoSet?.Invoke();
    RaisePropertyChanged(property);
    return true;
}
```

**Edit to clarify problem statement based on XY problem comment:**

- I have things bound to Game.Player.Gold
- On launch they work fine
- After doing XML deserialization and loading a saved state, some of the binding works when I navigate away and come back, but some dies completely
- Binding doesn't seem to like when I change the player instance or something, because it can't drill down into where the gold property is. Its weird to me that one textbox in the frame can rebind after i navigate, but one in the mainwindow can't
- I found a fix for this, using a setter on Game.Player directly, in addition to Game.Player.Gold, but I see some similar problems cropping up for other properties.
- Do I have some misunderstanding of how these things see one another?

Comment: How have you declared your properties? Are you using Fody?

Comment: Edited in the relevant properties I believe. I'm unsure what Fody is, so probably not using it. If its a framework, I just built this all myself to learn UWP stuff a while back for a test and now I'm using it to play with toher things like XML serialization.

Comment: How did you declare SetProperty?

Comment: Looks like the code I edited in got edited back out, I'll add it in again in a moment. What part of the code is showing as unreadable? it all shows in code blocks with formatting and syntax in my browser.

Comment: I think so: you flattened some tabs, I'll flatten stuff before I paste it in. Cheers.

Comment: @Sambardo Is `LoadGame` an event handler? `async void` should be avoided unless it is an event handler. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: LoadGame is not, its just a method on my GameModel. I think it boils down to a misunderstanding of the way databinding can see properties of my variables change, or the way xml deserialization is working and I thought the actual code would lead someone to seeing that I was just doing something incorrectly.

Comment: I tried to edit in a problem statement to clarify a bit. Unsure if it helps, but if I have time and can replicate it on a smaller scale then I'll open a new question with the repro. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating `myGame.Game.Player.Gold` live, so it will fetch the details from the Player class when the page reloads for the frame, but is missing the details to update it instantly upon change as RemainingTurns does. There may be an issue with accessors between the Frame and the Main Window.

```
await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => 
{
    this.Player = myGame.Player;
    this.Locations = myGame.Locations;
    this.RemainingTurns = myGame.RemainingTurns;
    // You need to get the value for Player.Gold
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. When I change gold values again later (no matter how many times) it will update in the frame, but not in the mainpage. If I have to relaod the mainpage for that, then why don't I for remainingTurns?

Are you referring to just the instant when I reset the player in the snippit above, or is this the reason the binding completely dies on the main page?

Comment: Do you mean it is unable to see the new player instance I  load into the player property without me reloading the mainpage or adding a set method to that property? I was under the impressing that since it was bound to the property in the game model it should be able to see that.

Comment: That should be edited in above, its an int with a setter to call SetProperty and raise and event for data binding. By adding a SetProperty to the player setter in GameModel it seems to have fixed some of it, but I'm still not sure I understand why the binding dies in the first place. This didn't fix the issue with another property, which is an ObservableCollection though.

Comment: No, I already had a setter for Player.Gold, which is in the post above, and why my binding worked at all. I added it for the Player property of the Game. Which resolves the issue for Gold specifically, but not some of the other properties such as an ObservableCollection

Comment: I did, but I'm still unsure why my addition was needed, which leads me to believe the issue is deeper and that what I added is just a bandaid with a specific side effect.

Comment: I added the setter in the post because I was asked to in the comments. I added an answer with my fix, but I'm still not convinced its the right fix. I'm not sure what part of the issue in the original post is unclear to you, so I'm not sure how to fix the language to help convey it.

Comment: There is and was a setter for Player.Gold. Data binding worked fine until I did a reload. Then it only works in one spot. Nothing binds player directly, only the properties of it, so a setter has not been needed to notify anything. My fix worked for the Player.Gold bindings, but not for many of the others, which leads me to believe that it is not the right fix.

Comment: my first sentence is "[..] where data-binding two text boxes to the same object works just fine, but after I load data back into my program via XML deserialization the binding fails on one of those text boxes." so again, I'm not sure where I've lost you. I appreciate you trying to help, but its clear we are having trouble communicating.

Comment: It does appear to be something along those lines, however your suggested fix didn't change anything. The one I posted worked, but I'm still not convinced its solving the underlying problem. Cheers though, it helped me down the right path.

Comment: I have not changed the original post at all. I'm still not sure which part of it wasn't clear to you. I added an answer with the fix I added separately. Its clear by this comment train that me and you are having a lot of trouble communicating. Once again, I appreciate the help, but it doesn't look like this discussion is getting us anywhere so in order to deescalate I'm going to disengage.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a Setter to the Player property in my Game

```
public Player Player
{
    get { return player; }
    set { SetProperty(player, value, () => player = value); }
}
```

This seems to fire off an event for anything subscribing to the properties of player that the player has been changed.

However, it didn't fix all the databinding issues I was seeing post load for different Player properties. For example, an ObservableCollection property still doesn't seem to bind right until I navigate frames.

It works fine when I start the game, but after I load in data from XML it still requires a navigation to populate correctly even with this fix added in.

I'm not sure if this is the right fix and I have a second issue or if this fix is just a weird bandaide for part of the issue. It might be a misunderstanding on the databinding aspect or on the deserialization aspect that I'm not getting.

Comment: I think you're unclear on the issue. That's fine. I have reread my post a few times and as I mentioned in your other thread, I am unsure which parts you are having trouble understanding, so I can't clarify it any further.